# Why does using the route app/* in an MVC app causes 405 error on post methods

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

So I have an MVC application, in it I have created a Web API controller (unity has been set up for both).

in my controller I have the following route "app/customer" for Get and Post methods.

When I call the get everything works fine but when I call the post I get a 405 error, saying the verb is not supported.

I change the route to api/customer and everything works fine.

Is there any reason for this? Is the route 'app/*' reserved for something with MVC or Web API?

Thanks

=========================================================================
Sample code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("app/customerImport")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ImportCustomers()
    {
        // code...

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

vs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/customerImport")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ImportCustomers()
    {
        // code...

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Show some code of the controller with actions and also route configuration.

Comment: Please include the controller. This could either be because of an omitted route in your config or on the controller itself. Show route config and the controller in question